# How can I move packages between Spacewalk channels?

Tags: spacewalk

How I can move a set of packages from one channel to another? I haven't found any option in the interface that'd let me do this.

My current workflow is to download the rpms, delete them from the channel (which appears to delete them from all of Spacewalk!), and then re-upload them with rhnpush. For obvious reasons this is clunky as hell. I must be missing something.

Which also makes me ask: How does one remove a package from a channel and not delete it from the entire System?

Answer (score 1):

In SpaceWalk 2.3 you can remove the packages from one channel and then add them to the new channel. I just completed this 5 minutes ago.

### Remove Packages

- Channels ->Manage Software Channels.
- Click on the channel that has the packages to be removed.
- Click on the packages tab and then List/Remove.
- Scroll to the bottom, click Select All and then Remove. You will be prompted to confirm removal.

*Note: This doesn't delete the packages it just removes them from the Channel. Packages can be removed under the Manage Software Packages menu.*

### Add Packages

- Channels ->Manage Software Channels.
- Click on the channel that you want to add the packages to.
- Click on the packages tab and then Add.
- Scroll to the bottom, click Select All and then Add Packages. You will be prompted to confirm the addition.

Hope that helps